# Codeigniter form validation process

Tags: php, codeigniter

I need to do form validation, I even did something like this on one of the validation cases:

```
if($this->input->post('submitted') =='yes') { // this is hidden field in the form 

if($this->form_validation->run() === TRUE) { 
  $gos['success'] = TRUE; 
  $this->admin_model->update_duela($duel_id);
 } else { 
  $gos['success'] = FALSE;
 }

}
```

and in view like:

```
if($success) {
        echo "Your post has been submitted!";
} else { 
        echo validatoin_errors(); 
}
```

Validation errors is great, I use it when validation fails. But when validation passes and form is submitted successfully, I usually do something like above.

Also, I could do something like this directly in view:

```
if($this->form_validation->run() === TRUE) { 
   echo "Your post has been submitted!";
 } else { 
   echo validation_errors(); 
}
```

but it’s not nice to do it in view. Is it?

Thanks for any suggestions

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add a variable in the controller:

```
if($this->form_validation->run() === TRUE) { 
     $data['message'] = 'Your post has been submitted!';
} else { 
     $data['message'] = validation_errors(); 
} 

$this->load->view('form', $data);
```

Call it in the view:

```
echo $message;
```

Comment: thanks, but still, you would need to do if(isset($message)) { echo $message; } , otherwise it would cause error on just page load without form being submitted

Comment: You don't need to check `isset` because $message has a value either way (if/else). If on some pages you don't have form validation at all, create a class variable `message`, set it `$this->message = '';` in the constructor and you won't need to check `isset`.